# Regenerate nginx logs

Tags: logging, hadoop, nginx, webserver, hive

I am currently logging all the activity on my web page to the nginx web-server which is in the file access.log . This file is incomprehensible because of its format, i wish to analyze these log files by exporting them to Hadoop Hive. However, hive cannot comprehend raw nginx logs. Thus I plan to regenerate these logs into JSON or CSV format and thereafter export them to hive where I can query and analyze the logs. Please suggest me some tools/methods which would enable me to do the above work.
Currently my nginx logs look like follows:

```
115.249.242.17 - - [01/Jun/2012:18:44:57 +0530] "GET /flashlayer?videoId=66127&playSessionId=VOD_66127_e04393db-0b40-44b1-aad8-aa2169ac71a710.32.6.1311338556485611&duration=0&playerState=playing&playerError=null HTTP/1.1" 200 86 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the log line you provided as an example, you should be able to create a Hive table on top of your HDFS data without any problem.

To get started you, can either use a MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe or RegexSerDe.
MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe is typically used when the fields of a record are delimited by the same character for example a tab or comma, etc. This is the SerDe used by default when you use `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'` in your `CREATE TABLE` statement. No need to specify the SerDe explicitly.

RegexSerDe is typically used when all the records match a particular regex. You can use grouping on this regex to extract out pieces that you would make your column data.
Example of RegexSerDe is available [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/gettingstarted.html#GettingStarted-ApacheWeblogData)

Note that RegexSerDe is worse performing than LazySimpleSerDe so you should prefer using LazySimpleSerDe where possible.

Also note that regardless of what SerDe you use, Hive presently has a limitation that one record of your table has to be present in one Hive. In order words, you can't have a record spilled over multiple rows of your data file (very common, if data is in XML) nor can you have multiple records present in one row. There are ways to get around this limitation, but if possible avoid such scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, **sed** is the best and simplest tool for such task.

Comment: I changed from mongodb to nginx to avoid transit processing of logs and can directly query on hive, this is just making it worse